# Can I override an element of a list, when original element is a length 2 numeric vector?

Tags: r

Can I override an element of a list in R language, when original element is a length 2 numeric vector?

```
l <- list(a=c(3,5),b=2,c=3) # OK, CREATED a list s.t. element 'a' is a 2-length vector
l['b'] <- 8 # OK, overrided a named element 'b' of the list with a 1-length vector.
l['a'] <- c(4,5) # "Warning" emitted
(l) # BAD
```

It throws warning. Worse, list is not updated with new value.  Need some workaround to update a pre-existing list's 2-length vector element. Potentially a whole new list constructor could be executed again -- avoiding the override of the element -- if it was apparent how to write the code generically. I don't know how to write that code in R yet.

This is R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: Use `l[['a']] <- c(4,5)`.  For lists, you should use double brackets to reference elements.

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
l[['a']] <- c(4,5)
```

Credit for answer goes to Sam Dickson.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your original answer may not have been far off!

Try `l['a'] <- list(c(4,5))`

You just had to format the replacement as a list. When you subset like `['a']`, a list is returned; when you subset as `[['a']]`, whatever is *in* the a'th element of that list is returned (in this case, a vector of length 2). That's why you had the trouble. You were supplying a length 2 to a length-1-something that *contained* a length-2-something.

Also, if you liked your own answer, you might also play with `l$a` when your list is named. Personally, I like your approach better, though (even though it's less compact, I like how it's consistent with subsetting other, similar, objects ... easier for my eye to catch subsetting actions when they all look the same).

Good luck!

Edit: just to visualize, note how the `a` element of the list was originally `c(3,5)`:

```
> l['a'] <- list(c(4,5)) # works!!!
> l
$a
[1] 4 5

$b
[1] 2

$c
[1] 3
```

Comment: @RichardScriven Good point! In fact, the name does nothing (even if it's different)! I'll change. Thank you.